# Amsmath has problems with $e^{\sum{x}}$

Tags: fonts, amsmath, errors, ubuntu

Running the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document} Test: $e^{\sum{x}}$ \end{document}
```

Dies, yet it runs just fine with the `\usepackage{amsmath}` commented out. The logs show:

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file fmex7.pfb): cannot open Type 1 font file for reading
```

Which seems to indicate a missing font. I've used amsmath quite a bit in the past and never come across the problem. A bit of googleing shows some other Debian users have had this problem but I'm not quite sure what to do here. I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 with most LaTeX packages installed.

Comment: Odd. That works just fine for me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This [seems to be caused by an out-of-date `$HOME/.texmf-var` folder](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/771bd8f21acb8571). Simply deleting that folder should solve the problem.

(I like Ubuntu, but its TeX packages are a mess.)

Comment: Like TH, I cannot reproduce the problem, and yet I don't have the named font file either. This points to the OP having somehow a screwed up font map. Kudos for tracking down that the error is caused by an error in `$HOME`.

Comment: That solved it! This may have come about at some point when I installed a font a long time back. Thanks!